# How do I get the node ID for a node associated with my taxonomy term?

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms

How do I get the node ID for a node associated with my taxonomy term with the Devel module?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Terms have a term ID number (tid) and nodes have a node id number (nid). Terms are applied to nodes so nodes can be associated to terms and vice versa.

Devel module can show the structure of a taxonomy term. To achieve this:

- Download and enable the devel.module
- Ensure you are logged in with a user who has the `Access developer information` permission
- Browse to the taxonomy term you want to inspect
- Click the Devel tab if it is visible

  - If it is not visible, that is likely either a permissions issue or a theme issue - to fix a theme issue you could try changing to a core theme like Bartik
- Then you should see some output like this: [image: devel rendering of a term]
- You can click tokens or Render or other sub-tabs as well
- This shows the tid and other values associated with the term, but not the nid of nodes associated with the term